# My package is not recognizing the exported functions of an imported package in R

Tags: r, r-package

I am writing an R package. 
Using roxygen2, I have this processor statement:

```
##' @import Other_Package
```

As I understand it, this statement would import every exported function from Other_Package.
But when I ran:

```
devtools::test()
```

Some test cases failed because it wasn't able to find some functions of Other_Package.

Comment: Please make sure you have DESCRIPTION file in your package with all the dependency packages. Review the following guidelines for any help http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: @NaremanDarwish Other_Package is under "Imports" in the Description file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to include `Other_Package` in you DESCRIPTION file.  You can do this very readily with:

```
usethis::use_package("Other_Package")
```

Additionally, make sure you re-render your documentation before tests.  This will include recreating your NAMESPACE file. `roxygen2` is great and will handle this part for you:

```
devtools::document()
```

To confirm, go to your NAMESPACE file and make sure `import(Other_Package)` is found there.  When using `roxygen2`, do NOT edit the NAMESPACE file by hand.

Now, your tests should run normally:

```
devtools::test()
```

---

#### Alternative Solutions

Rather than relying on your NAMESPACE, I'd recommend you make explicit calls inside your package.  So any function from `Other_Package` would have the `Other_Package::` prefix (e.g. `function1()` would be `Other_Package::function1()`).  Do this throughout your entire package, including any tests.